# Reactjs: ReactTable css doesn't load css using import in js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-table

I am trying ReactTable using [this link](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme)

**Problem:**

In my component when I try importing

```
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
```

**css doesnt get import**

When I inspect I see this as css url

```
blob:http://localhost:8080/cfd98537-05a8-4091-9345-d6ae877d3d25
```

but this works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/react-table/react-table.css">
```

**Files:**

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("dist"),
    filename: "main.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin]
};
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import EmpTable from "./components/Emptable.js";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

function renderApp() {
  ReactDOM.render(<EmpTable />, document.getElementById("root"));
}

renderApp();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>React and Webpack4</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/react-table/react-table.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Emptable.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import axios from "axios";

const column = [
  {
    Header: "User ID",
    accessor: "userId"
  },
  {
    Header: "ID",
    accessor: "id"
  },
  {
    Header: "Title",
    accessor: "title"
  },
  {
    Header: "Completed",
    accessor: "completed"
  }
];

class EmpTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("Loading...");
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: [], isLoading: false };
    this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    this.loadData();
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.log("componentDidCatch");
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    console.log(error);
  }

  loadData() {
    console.log("loadData");
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ value: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.loadData}>Refresh Grid</button>
        <ReactTable data={this.state.value} columns={column} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EmpTable;
```

Comment: The `blob:http://localhost:8080/cfd98537-05a8-4091-9345-d6ae877d3d25` gets emitted for hot reloading to work. In production mode, you'll not see that. Based on what you've shown, I don't see anything wrong. What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using CSS-Modules. Your WebPack module rule will generate a unique name for each CSS class when the document loads.

see this line in your config:  `localIdentName: "[name][local][hash:base64]"`

When you `include` the react-table.css file in your project, css-modules will format the css names to keep them locally scoped, for example, the resulting mark-up: ( `react__table___2zWw1`) but react-table isn't using the locally scoped css names in *it's* code.

Your link to the stylesheet (link rel=...) should work, but if you're looking to use CSS-Modules, you must exclude the file from the modules loader, or exclude all of node_modules/react-table:

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   exclude: [/node_modules/],
   ...
}
```

You could try the above, or alternatively exclude specific .css files from using the module loader, based on their filename. In this case, you'd have to reference a custom **react-table.customCSS.css** file by copying it locally to your project and importing it again:

```
<code>
 test: /\.customCSS.css$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'style-loader',
    }, {
      loader: 'css-loader',
    }],
  },
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me when i include

```
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
```

in main js file, where ever use react-table